# Counting grouped cells excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Currently I have a excel table that looks like this

```
  A            B             C             D             E             F             G
  ID          NAME          DATE          ITEM                        2020           3        
 1234         Alex       09-20-2020      Carrot                       2019           2
 1234         Alex       09-20-2020       Onion
 1234         Alex       09-20-2019      Carrot 
 1234         Alex       09-20-2019     Mushroom           
 1234         Alex       09-20-2020       Pasta          
 1345        Morgan      09-20-2020       Pasta  
 1345        Morgan      09-20-2020    Tomato Sauce 
 1145        Jayson      09-20-2020    Tomato Sauce 
 1145        Jayson      09-20-2020     Cream Sauce 
 1345        Morgan      09-20-2019       Pasta  
 1345        Morgan      09-20-2019    Tomato Sauce
```

I want to be able to count the unique customers for each year using excel functions. This is so that the functions can be transferred to a different computers without setting up the custom functions.

The proccess currently can be done in excel without function by: adding filter to each column, filtering to only show the intended year, using remove duplicate to remove duplicates in `NAME`, and finally counting the rows (giving reslts seen in G2 & G3). However, I want to be able to do that through excel functions. So far what I have is that I am able to count unique values through

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(B2:B12)>0,MATCH(B2:B12,B2:B12,0),""),IF(LEN(B2:B12)>0,MATCH(B2:B12,B2:B12,0),''))>0,1))}
```

Additionally I am also able to `SUMPRODUCT()` for counting a array with multiple condition so for now I have combined the above forumla with

```
SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C2:C12)=G1)+0)
```

My initial idea was to add the first function into the SUMPRODUCTI() since the first function could also produce a array that it could count. However that quickly did not work as it did not count the unique values corresponding to the year.

My question here is if there is any way to what would be a grouping function so that I can take unique values that are within a year, without transforming the data (through filters of deletion of duplicates). My current understanding with `SUMPRODUCT()` is that it will only look for unique values in the entire column but not within the range given for the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got numeric ID's which you should make use of. If you have got Excel O365, in `G1` use:

```
=COUNT(UNQIUE(FILTER(A$2:A$12,YEAR(C$2:C$12)=F1)))
```

With older versions, use this CSE-entered formula:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(YEAR(C$2:C$12)=F1,A$2:A$12),A$2:A$12)>0))
```

And drag down.

Comment: There are also stuations where the ID is blank and only the name is there. What wouldbe the solution then? sorry for not clarifying earlier.